# Call one stored procedure of two insert table query from two method on one click

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two methods with different info.In these both method, i'm calling one procedure to insert data into two tables. Suppose i have these two methods:

```
 method 1()
    {
    int id;
    string name;
//inserting id, name into db's table1 using procedure
// here i'm also calling stored procedure with insert query for table1
    } 
    method 2()
    {
    int ID;
    string address;
//inserting ID(same as id from metohd1/table1), address into db's table2 using procedure
//here i'm also calling same procedure with insert query for table2
    }
```

And i want to use these two methods in one method for one click submit. For this, im using method3 like:

```
method3()
{
method1();
method2();
}
```

Acc to this method3, i can call methods for inserting data using procedure. In stored procedure, i'm using two insert query for two different tables.

```
create procedure ABC
(
@id varchar();
@name varchar();
@address varchar();
)
AS
Begin
insert into table1(id, name) values(@id, @name)
insert into table2(ID, address) select id, @address from table1 where id=@id
End
```

But this is not working for me. Please check where i'm wrong. Hope u understand whaT is my query.

Comment: Your store procedure is executed proper, I think it should be data type varchar() is some thing problemetic. We have to define value to that

Answer (score 0):

If your procedure expects three parameters, it must be executed with all three parameters. You can't execute it once with only `id` and `name` and once with only `id` and `address`. You should either separate the insert statements into two different procedures, or join `method1()` and `method2()` into a single method.

I would suggest the first option, based on SRP - single responsibility principle.